# Linking a library in premake 5

Tags: premake

I have the following library:
library.dll.a
In premake 5 I put:
links {"library.dll"}
I've tried everything but to no avail.
I'm probably wrong and don't consider all the options of the lua language.

ognizes It only reclibrary and not library.dll, what should I do?

Comment: `links{"rary.dll"}`. as premake add "lib" prefix and ".a" suffix automatically see [doc](https://premake.github.io/docs/links/).

Comment: "library.dll.a" is strange name... .a suffix is for static library whereas dll are for dynamic library...